# Does qplot with stat=identity argument exist in the syntax? Checked the documentation but couldn't find

Tags: r, ggplot2

R graphics cook book winston chang page 12 gives the syntax given below that does not work

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(BOD$Time, BOD$demand, geom="bar", stat="identity")
# Convert the x variable to a factor, so that it is treated as discrete
qplot(factor(BOD$Time), BOD$demand, geom="bar", stat="identity")
```

Error:

Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
`stat` is deprecated

I know that ggplot has geom_bar with stat=identity, just checking if qplot has as i dont see in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

`?geom_bar`

There are two types of bar charts: geom_bar() and geom_col(). geom_bar() makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in each group (or if the weight aesthetic is supplied, the sum of the weights). If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use geom_col() instead. geom_bar() uses stat_count() by default: it counts the number of cases at each x position. geom_col() uses stat_identity(): it leaves the data as is.

When making a bar chart, only specify x *or* y. Switch to column `col` chart to use both.

`qplot(BOD$Time, BOD$demand, geom="col")`